# PHP - function not returning value inside isset

Tags: php

I have a function call `find_student_by_id()` with one `arg` complete code below.

```
function find_student_by_id($student_number){
  global $con;
  $safe_student_number = prep($student_number);

  $sql  = "SELECT * ";
  $sql .= "FROM studeprofile ";
  $sql .= "WHERE StudentNumber = '{$safe_student_number}'";
  $sql .= "LIMIT 1";
  $student_set = mysqli_query($con, $sql);
  confirm_query($student_set);
  if($student = mysqli_fetch_assoc($student_set)){
    return $student;
  } else {
    return null;
  }
}
```

this function work fine if I call it anywhere in the page, but if i use it inside `isset` function not returning any `value`.

```
$student = find_student_by_id('id-201');
```

if use outside the isset it give me value `echo $student['student_number'];`

but if i used it inside `isset` no value will return.

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
  $student_number = $student['student_number'];
}
```

**complete code inside** cor.php

```
<?php
  $student = find_student_by_id($_GET['student_number']);
  //if(!$student){
  //  redirect_to('home.php');
  //}
  //$_SESSION['sn'] = $student['StudentNumber'];
?>
<?php
  if(isset($_GET['subject_id'])){
    $subject = find_subject_id($_GET['subject_id']);
  }
  //if(!$subject){
  //  redirect_to('cor.php');
  //}

?>
<?php
  if(isset($_POST['submit'])){

  $subject_code = $subject['SubjectCode'];
  $description = $subject['Description'];
  $lec_unit = "";
  $lab_unit = "";
  $section = "";
  $labtime = "";
  $sched_time = "";
  $room = "";
  $instructor = "";
  $sem = "";
  $sy = "";
  $sn = $student['StudentNumber'];
  $term = "";
  $fn = $student['FirstName'];
  $mn = $student['MiddleName'];
  $ln = $student['LastName'];
  $course = $student['Course'];
  $yl = $student['YearLevel'];

  $sql  = "INSERT INTO registration(";
  $sql .= "SubjectCode, Description, LecUnit, LabUnit, ";
  $sql .= "Section, LabTime, SchedTime, Room, Instructor, ";
  $sql .= "Sem, SY, StudentNumber, Term, FirstName, MiddleName, ";
  $sql .= "LastName, Course, YearLevel";
  $sql .= ")VALUES(";
  $sql .= "'{$subject_code}', '{$description}', '{$lec_unit}', '{$lab_unit}', '{$section}', '{$labtime}', ";
  $sql .= "'{$sched_time}', '{$room}', '{$instructor}', '{$sem}', '{$sy}', '{$sn}', ";
  $sql .= "'{$term}', '{$fn}', '{$mn}', '{$ln}', '{$course}', '{$yl}'";
  $sql .= ")";
  $cor = mysqli_query($con, $sql);
  if($cor){
    redirect_to('cor.php?student_number='.$subject_code);
  } else {
    die(mysqli_error($con));
  }

  }
?>


<div>
  Student Number : <?php echo $student['StudentNumber']; ?><br />
  Name: <?php echo fullname($student); ?>

  <a class="popup" href="search-subject-cor.php">Add subject</a>

  <br /> <br />
  <p><?php echo $subject['SubjectCode']; ?></p>
  <p><?php echo $subject['description']; ?></p>

  <form method="post" action="cor.php">
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Add subject" />
  </form>
```

Comment: But where you were using this `isset` within function or outside the scope of function

Comment: and who did you check if **$student['student_number']** is set?

Comment: I dont see any form, For what are you using the `isset`?

Comment: I use a single page to process data from the form so i need to use `isset` to deal with the error `(Undefined variable)`

Comment: if you are going to use `$student_number` it is a good practice that you declare and initialize (`$student_number  = 0`) the variable outside of the  if condition and then you overwrite the value. Otherwise you will use a variable that it might not being declare.

Answer (score 1):

```
if(isset($_GET['subject_id'])){
         ^
    $subject = find_subject_id($_GET['subject_id']);
}
```

Compare that with

```
<form method="post" action="cor.php">
              ^
```

And delete the question :)